# function stuff. please explain how it works

Tags: python, function

This code is supposed to print a 5x5 board of o's lined up each row of 5 o's in a new line.

```
board = []
for x in range(0,5):
    # runs code 5 times.(range of 0,5 = 5)
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

def print_board(i):
    for row in i:
    print row
print print_board(board)
```

What does the second block have do do with the first block? also, when I don't put in board as the argument, it gives me an error.

I tried switching the argument with other things but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly your problem is? You define the board and print it. What part of it do you not understand (besides that it won't run because the `print row` isn't indented)?

Comment: i think im starting to understand it. but anyway,theres 2 block of code. what does the second one have to do with the first and why does the argument have to be board

Comment: In the first part you define `board`, in the second part you print it. Of course you need the argument `board` because that is what you want to use in your `print_board` function (known there as `i`).

Comment: Basic Python, read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

We first define board to be [].

Then we add a the element `[O]*5` (this just gives five O's) to it, five times.

So the array is now `[OOOOO,OOOOO,OOOOO,OOOOO,OOOOO]`.

Then the second block defines a general function `print_board(i)`, which prints every element of a certain array in a new row.

For example, if `board2` is `[WW,WW]`, then `print_board(board2)` will print

```
WW
WW
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using python 2.X. Your board is an list type which is empty at the beginning. In for loop for range 0 to 5 (actually its 0 to 4 including 0). The ["0"]*5 causes string a list to be created with "0" repeated five times. If you try to use "Test!"*5, it will cause Test!Test!Test!Test!Test! to output in the interactive window. Now at the end of this loop [['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0'], ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']] will be assigned to the board which is a list of lists (nesting of list).

In the second block, for loop takes each row of the board i.e. each nested list from the list and prints the same. Now should that print statement in the second block be indented inside the for loop? You've kept them in the same indention. If you don't pass any argument to the second block, the interpreter will notify the exception because it expects iterable parameter. So any iterable type will work like dictionaries, set etc. All the best with your python venture.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little structure will help you understand it better ;)

```
# function definition

def print_board(i):       # definition of function "board"
    for row in i:         # this function can be called from anywhere
        print row         # in your program and requires an argument
                          # to know what to do

# main program

board = []                # create variable board

for x in range(0,5):      # insert values ...
    # runs code 5 times.(range of 0,5 = 5)
    board.append(["O"] * 5)

print_board(board)        # tell function to print this variable
```